# Scroll background-image with content when div overflows

Tags: css, background, overflow

Ive got a container div with overflow:scroll;. It contains a tiled background div (width:100%; height: 100%;) with lots of draggable divs over the top.

When the draggable divs make the container div overflow, how do I get the tiled background to cover the overflow as well?

[image: visual example]

Thanks!

Comment: why do you use an extra div for the background image? you could apply the image to the container div via css background property, no?

Comment: If I am understanding correctly, there is no extra div for the background image. There are several divs that can be dragged placed in a single container div. The container div has the background and the overflow is set to scroll. The problem is when a draggable div is moved outside the container div. The background does not expand and the background is blank. I don't think it is possible to expand the background beyond the limits of the div it has been added to. A link would be nice so we can see the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @schellmax suggested in the comments, the obvious solution would seem to be to apply the background-image to the container div, instead of another div inside that. That would be the most elegant solution.

If that's not a possibility, such as when you want to use a transparent repeating background-image over the container div's background, then you might try not specifying a specific width on the inner `div` (`width: auto` or `width: inherit`). Then, for the height, you may try `height: inherit`. If that doesn't work (I haven't tested it), perhaps a javascript solution is in order - although still, I'd rather go with what I said in the first paragraph.

Comment: Thanks for the response.
If I apply the background to the container then it doesn't scroll with the content (in webkit anyway).
If I use auto or inherit then the background disappears.
Is JavaScript the only solution then? Seems like I'm missing something simple.

Comment: Oh I see. I doubt that there will be a CSS solution then. Your best bet will be a JavaScript solution, that sets the width and height of the inner element when the inner width of the container changes.

Comment: There is an example on http://www.tizag.com/cssT/background.php about half way down the page. The scrolling background works when you scroll the whole page but not when you scroll within the textbox, which is what I want.